# in the context of real value matrix are conjugate transposing and regular transposing the same?

Tags: linear-algebra, python

assume a matrix does not have any complex entry.

```
a = np.matrix(np.arange(6).reshape(3,2))
a
matrix([[0, 1],
        [2, 3],
        [4, 5]])
```

(regular) transposing this matrix

```
a.T
matrix([[0, 2, 4],
        [1, 3, 5]])
```

and conjugate transposing this matrix

```
a.getH()
matrix([[0, 2, 4],
        [1, 3, 5]])
```

seems to have the same output.

the conjecture above is based on the Python NumPy.

is it true mathematically?

Comment: Conjugate of real number is itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $A\in \textsf{M}_{m\times n}(F)$, their conjugate transpose $A^*\in \textsf{M}_{n\times m}(F)$ is defined as
$$(A^*)_{ij}=\overline{A_{ji}}$$
for $1\le i\le n$, $1\le j\le m$. If $F=\mathbb{R}$, then $\overline{A_{ji}}=A_{ji}$. So, yes, it's correct to say that
$$A^*=A^t$$

Comment: thanks for your answer. would you please explain what do A, M, F stand for? A seems to be a real value matrix. what about others?

Comment: $F$ is an arbitrary field. $\textsf{M}_{m\times n}(F)$ is the set of all matrices with entries in the field $F$. So $A$ is a matrix with all their entries in $F$.